# Server side error generating RSS - what to return back to user/RSS reader?

Tags: javascript, .net, xml, rss, server

Say you have a server side route that generates & returns an RSS feed. If a server side error occurs what should be returned back to the user/RSS reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think a HTTP 5xx error would be appropriate...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error